# Trouble Writing Update Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write an update script for the following table.

```
Id        int,
Title     nvarchar(100),
ProgramId int,
EventId   int,
SortOrder int
```

I want to set the `SortOrder` column to 1 through N, as sorted by the `Id` column. However, I want the number to restart when either `ProgramId` or `EventId` changes. That is, I'd like the numbering sequence 1...N for each row with the same `ProgramId` and `EventId` values, and then restart the numbering for the next `ProgramId` and `EventId` values.

I know I could use `ROW_NUMBER` to get a row number based on the current sorting, but I don't see how I could restart the number when one of those other two columns changes. Is this even possible?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProgramId, EventId ORDER BY Id)

Comment: @Aaron, is it possible to stick that in an update statement?

Comment: Yes, @RBarryYoung has done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
;WITH cte As
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProgramId, EventId ORDER BY Id) As RN
    FROM   YourTable
)
UPDATE  cte
SET     SortOrder = RN
```